# Многопоточность с использованием fork() и join()

Tags: java

Существует готовый написанный графический интерфейс с помощью которого пользователь выбирает директорию для поиска, и вписывает название файла для поиска в этой директории и его поддиректориях.

Для реализации задачи необходимо пользоваться `fork()` и `join()`.

К сожалению, при выполнении задачи происходит бесконечный поиск по первой указанной директории, а поддиректории не затрагиваются.

```
public class mainController {
    private void search() {
        ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool();
        // chosenDirectory - директория, которую выбрал пользователь для поиска в ней файла.
        MyRecursiveTask myRecursiveTask = new MyRecursiveTask(chosenDirectory); 
        forkJoinPool.invoke(myRecursiveTask);
    }
}

public class MyRecursiveTask extends RecursiveTask<File> {

    private File directory;

    public MyRecursiveTask(File directory) {
        this.directory = directory;
    }

    mainController mainController = new mainController();

    @Override
    protected File compute() {

        String filename = mainController.getFilename();
        File directory = mainController.getFilepath();

        //список подзадач
        List<MyRecursiveTask> subtasks = new LinkedList<>(); 
        File result = null;

        if(directory.listFiles() !=null && directory.isDirectory()) {
            for(File el: directory.listFiles()) {
                if(el.getName().equals(filename)) result = el;
                else if(el.isDirectory() && el.listFiles() != null){
                    MyRecursiveTask subTask = new MyRecursiveTask(el);
                    subTask.fork();
                    subtasks.add(subTask);
                }
            }

            for (MyRecursiveTask a: subtasks){
                result = a.join();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: может быть только один файл? что должна вернуть задача, если файла нет?

Comment: Да, может быть только один файл. Если файла нет, тогда просто возращает налл.

Comment: посмотрите на пример, который есть в документации. проверка на окончание рекурсии должна быть в начале метода и только потом вы должны продолжать поиск.

Comment: Предположу, что listFiles возвращает в том числе текущую директорию в виде записи `.`, и таким образом весь алгоритм уходит в рекурсию.

Comment: Проверял несколько раз, listFiles() возвращает только директории и файлы внутри.

Comment: локальная переменная `File directory = mainController.getFilepath();` перекрывает поле объекта

Comment: Спасибо, действительно в этом была причина.

Answer (score 1):

В качестве решения могу предложить вот такой вариант

```
class MyRecursiveTask extends RecursiveTask<File> {
    private final String fileName;
    private final File startDirectory;

    public MyRecursiveTask(String fileName, File startDirectory) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.startDirectory = startDirectory;
    }

    @Override
    protected File compute() {
        File[] files = startDirectory.listFiles((_dir, name) -> name.equals(fileName));
        if (files == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (files.length > 0) {
            return files[0];
        }

        return Arrays.stream(startDirectory.listFiles(File::isDirectory))
                .map(dir -> new Finder(fileName, dir).fork())
                .map(ForkJoinTask::join)
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
    }
}
```

Тут нет завязки на контроллер и вызвать надо с двумя параметрами - имя файла и начальная директория.